# Is it possible to stream webcam live?

Tags: jquery, streaming, webcam

The plugin at http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ makes use of images from my webcam.

I would like to send these images to a streaming server instead.

Is this possible?

Comment: I also want this, I want to create a webchat, but I'm not sure how could I share/broadcast the webcam.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.scriptcam.com can do exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I know that [VLC](http://www.videolan.org) will function as a streaming media server. I have never used it to stream from a webcam but it does list that capability in its feature list.

Most people only know VLC as a media player and not as a server of media. There are other servers out there. It really depends on what your platform is, whether you want something open source or commercial, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Jquery plugin you linked is flash-based and works with still images. You can post still images with AJAX to your server and send to the partner.

If you are looking for a video ( >= 10 fps) chat, then currently flas is the only browser-based solution of encoding and transmitting multimedia in (near) realtime. Check out [Red5](http://www.red5.org/), there are even sample applications for video chat.

If you want to broadcast a live stream (to many users) please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page:
http://www.jqueryrain.com/2013/10/best-jquery-webcam-plugin-example/

There are some jquery plugins shown for capturing image and streaming of images.
Among of them, I really liked scriptcam(http://www.scriptcam.com/index.cfm) API. It has many functionality.